# Is it possible to tell composer to always choose lower package version, when there are more then one matching requiremnets

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a package which uses "satooshi/php-coveralls" package to calculate coverage on TravisCI. Coveralls composer.json requires:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "guzzle/guzzle": "^2.8|^3.0",
        "psr/log": "^1.0",
        "symfony/config": "^2.1|^3.0",
        "symfony/console": "^2.1|^3.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^2.0|^3.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^2.0|^3.0"
    },
```

My package doesn't use any of those packages directly, but I am supporting PHP 5.4 which in turn requires that lower version of all them are used. Is there a way to tell composer to use guzzle/guzzle: ^2.8 rather then ^3.0, symfony/config: ^2.1 rather then ^3.0 etc. Currently when I run composer install, higher versions are installed so the build fails on PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a prefer-lowest option when running composer. Here are more details

https://evertpot.com/testing-composer-prefer-lowest/

Answer (score 1):

You can use ~ ("tilde") for that..

```
"guzzle/guzzle": "~2.8",
```

which means

```
>= 2.8 < 3.0.0
```

also

```
"guzzle/guzzle": "^2.8",
```

should work

evenmore any higher versions of 2. but less than 3.

```
"guzzle/guzzle": "^2.*",
```

or

```
"guzzle/guzzle": "~2.*",
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

Comment: I know I can do that, but I don't think I should have to require a package, I'm not using. Not least of all, because my required package might change its dependencies, let's say go to 2.7 and then my build will fail again. That's why, I'm asking if there is a way to tell the composer to choose lower second hand dependencies, so to call them. I mean it's not a tragedy if in the end, I have to do what you suggest, but I'd prefer more elegant solution, if there is one